# I'd like to record a logged user info, who visited a wordpress page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've written this script and added it as a shortcode to a specific page, but after visiting the page nothing will be saved in a table.

```
<?php
 function save_logged_in(){
 $user=wp_get_current_user();

 if ($user->is_user_logged_in()){
 $page_id = get_queried_object_id();

   if ($page_id =="228"){

  global $wpdb;

  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'session_capture';  

  $user=$user->user_login;
  $email=$user->user_email;
  $name=$user->user_firstname;
 $family=$user->user_lastname;
  $dt=current_time('mysql');

  $wpdb->insert($table_name,array('login_name'=>$user, 'email'=>$email, 'fname'=>$name,   'lname'=>$family, 'date'=>$dt));

   }
  }
 }
```

?>

what is the problem?

I'm trying to record user info directly from the wordpress page to a table, but nothing happened after running the script.

Comment: 1. Add error checking  2. commit your transaction or make sure autocommit is enabled.

Comment: It's possible your code shown above never ran. Please [edit] your question to show us where you registered your shortcode. Also read about WP_DEBUG_LOG.

Comment: Actually I've added the code as a shortcode block at the top of a page, and I guess code runs everytime page loads. Because if I add a wrong line of code intentioanlly, after that page won't loads and shows error. However it's a good point to check the LOG file. Is there any other way to run the code other than shortcode blocks?